# regression analysis on data from one individual

Tags: regression

Let's say I have data from a single individual that I'd like to model.
I'm not sure if regression is suitable since the different values come from the same individual and are therefore not independent.
For example, would it be statistically valid to run a regression analysis on these data if they came from the same individual?:

```
df <- data.frame(x=runif(24, min=0, max=100), c=rep(c("A","B"),each=12))
lm(y~c, data=df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have to make some strong assumptions along with a time series analysis. For example, you measure the blood pressures of the same individual once every morning and collect data for 30 days in a row. You may adopt an [AR(1)](https://otexts.com/fpp2/AR.html) model, with some stationary assumptions. In other words, with only one independent individual, you make assumptions to absorb correlation into some latent terms (a stationary random process, say), and finally, get back independence.